# Função Geolocation.getCurrentPosition não funciona no Chrome 50.0

Tags: javascript, html5, jsf-2.2, google-chrome, geolocalização

tenho um sistema em JSF que solicita ao usuário permissão para ler suas coordenadas, esse sistema sempre funcionou, mas apos a ultima atualização do Chrome, o mesmo parou de funcionar. Alguém esta passando por isso com essa nova versão(50.0.2661.75):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getGeo(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        sendGeo(position.coords);
    },showError);
}
function showError(error) {
    var msgError = "";
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            msgError = "Usuário negou o pedido de Geolocalização."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            msgError = "As informações de localização não está disponível."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            msgError = "O pedido para obter a localização do usuário expirou."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            msgError = "Ocorreu um erro desconhecido."
            break;
        default:
            msgError = "-";
            break;
    }
    sendGeo({msgerror:msgError});
}
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
        getGeo();
    } 
});
</script>
```

Percebi que o navegador nem informa reconhece que esse site esta solicitando a localização.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema. Acredito que o site terá que ser acessado por HTTPS, única forma de resolver.